# Why is my camera's quaternion not slerping in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, quaternions

I'm trying to make a smooth camera rotation with a dampening effect whenever I scroll. My code show below works, in that my `this.camera`'s quaterion value of "x" updates whenever I scroll, however, it's "snappy". It doesn't ease or interpolate every time I scroll. Instead, it jumps to the new value. I'm not sure why this is the case.

```
export default class Experience {
    constructor(options = {}) {
    //...
        this.camera = new Camera();
        this.renderer = new Renderer(this.canvas);
        this.scrollTargetPosition = this.camera.quaternion;
        this.scrollTargetPosition.setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),0);

        this.animate();
        this.onMouseScroll();
    }

    onMouseScroll() {
        window.addEventListener("mousewheel", (event) => {
            this.lerp2 = true;
            if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
                this.scrollTargetPosition.x += 0.05;
            } else {
                this.scrollTargetPosition.x -= 0.05;
            }
            console.log(this.scrollTargetPosition); // Equal Each other-----------------
            console.log(this.camera.quaternion); // Equal Each other-----------------
        });
    }

    animate() {
        this.camera.quaternion.slerp(this.scrollTargetPosition, 0.9);
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

    }
}
```

I have a feeling since I print them out and they're both the same that's the problem (it's slerping to the same vector - so effectively no interpolation), but I don't know why changing another variables changes the cameras before the `animate()` function. I also switched `0.9` to `0.1` and others but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is this line:

```
this.scrollTargetPosition = this.camera.quaternion;
```

changed to a new Quaterion instead of setting it to the cameras':

```
this.scrollTargetPosition = new THREE.Quaternion();
```

However, this does not fix the slerping issue, as it only sometimes interpolates, but sometimes doesn't. Sometimes it doesn't even move on scroll even though the target is different.